comparison between two strings for a group of unsorted values
My SQL returns 2 columns with concatenated strings, I split both the columns in power query and I want to use DAX to do a comparison on the values in both the columns for every ID column. The measure should show the return the distinct count of ColumnA when Agency = Yes and when either of the mismatch conditions are met:

either Region A and Region B is null for every ColumnA and date
Either of the regions have a mismatch value for every ColumnA and date
Either one of the Regions is null and the other has value for every ColumnA and date.
From the below example, For 11/1/2024, the total should be 2(123 and 567 are mismatch, 345 is not counted as Agency = No),for 11/8/2024 the total will be 1(345 is match)
The measure for the whole population should return a count of 2 (123, 345).

Please let me know the DAX that is needed for this situation. In SQL i used String_split to compare the values



Date
ColumnA
Agency
RegionA
RegionB




11/01/2024
123
Yes
Phoenix
Phoenix


11/01/2024
123
Yes
Charlotte



11/08/2024
123
Yes
Phoenix
Phoenix


11/08/2024
123
Yes
Charlotte
Charlotte


11/01/2024
345
No
Edison



11/01/2024
345
No
Atlanta



11/01/2024
567
Yes

Tampa


11/01/2024
567
Yes

Raleigh


11/01/2024
567
Yes

Memphis


11/08/2024
345
Yes
Atlanta
Edison


11/08/2024
345
Yes
Edison



11/08/2024
567
Yes
Tampa
Tampa


11/08/2024
567
Yes
Raleigh
Raleigh



Wrote the query in SQL but user wants a drillthrough of the details that make the counts so trying to achieve the result with DAX

Assuming I correctly understand your requirements:

Mismatch Count = 
VAR FilteredData =
    FILTER (
        'Table',
        'Table'[Agency] = "Yes"
            && (
                -- Condition 1: Either RegionA or RegionB is NULL
                ISBLANK('Table'[RegionA]) || ISBLANK('Table'[RegionB])
                ||
                -- Condition 2: Mismatch between RegionA and RegionB
                'Table'[RegionA] <> 'Table'[RegionB]
            )
    )
VAR DistinctIDs = DISTINCT ( SELECTCOLUMNS ( FilteredData, "DistinctColumnA", 'Table'[ColumnA] ) )
RETURN
COUNTROWS ( DistinctIDs )

